# How to use chaining in Kotlin to parse JSON like python

Tags: python, android, json, kotlin, gson

Suppose i have a JSON as below:

```
sampleJSON = {

"key1": {
        "nestedkey1": "nestedvalue1",
        "nestedkey2": "nestedvalue2"
},
"key2": {
        "nestedkey3": "nestedvalue3",
        "nestedkey4": "nestedvalue4"
}   
}
```

Now i want to access value of **nestedkey2** so in python(as it is also python dictionary) we can access like,

```
print(sampleJSON.get("key1").get("nestedkey2"))
```

But in kotlin, we have to explicitely first get outer JSON object and then the inner value like this:

```
val outerJO = JSONObject(sampleJSON)
val innerJO = outerJO.getJSONObject("key1")
println(innerJO.get("nestedkey2"))
```

Is there any way to use chaining like python in Kotlin to access nested JSON objects? Any library which can do it?

Comment: Why not `println (JSONObject(sampleJSON).optJSONObject("key1").optString("nestedkey2"))`?

Comment: What if nestedkey2 is JSONObject(or anything) rather than string value while fetching json at runtime? Suppose it could be anything.

Answer (score 4):

That's easy to achieve using extension functions. For example with Gson library:

```
import com.google.gson.JsonElement
import com.google.gson.JsonParser

fun main() {
    val jsonString = """
        {

"key1": {
        "nestedkey1": "nestedvalue1",
        "nestedkey2": "nestedvalue2"
},
"key2": {
        "nestedkey3": "nestedvalue3",
        "nestedkey4": "nestedvalue4"
}   
}
    """
    val json = JsonParser().parse(jsonString)
    val result = json["key1"]["nestedkey2"] // Even shorter that in Python

    println(result)
}

private operator fun JsonElement.get(key: String) = this.asJsonObject.get(key)
```

Comment: Come on guy, you specified that JsonElement  only as JsonObject. It is not work with the Array situation.